# Integrability and Continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Suppose $f(x)\geq 0$ for each $x\in [a,b]$ and $f(c)>0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$. Then $\int^{b}_{a}f>0$

My Attempt: Suppose $f$ is continuous for for $\epsilon=\frac{f(c)}{2}>0$ $\exists$ $delta_1>0$ such that whenever $x \in (c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)$, we have $f(x)>f(c)$.

Now, how do I show that $\int^{b}_{a} f(x)$ $\geq \delta_1 \frac{f(c)}{2}$?

Comment: You can break the integral. $\int_{a}^{b}f=\int_{a}^{c-\delta_{1}}f+\int_{c-\delta_{1}}^{c+\delta_{1}}f+\int_{c+\delta_{1}}^{b}f$. You already know that $\int_{c-\delta_{1}}^{c+\delta_{1}}f>0$. What can you say about the anothers integrals?

Comment: @Mateus Rocha You're assuming $(c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1) \subseteq [a,b]$, right?

Comment: Yeah, but If its not possible, it means that $c=a$ or $c=b$. So, you can break the integral in a similar way.

Comment: @MateusRocha why does it mean that $c=a or c=b$? if its not possible?

Comment: By the continuity of $f$, if $f(c)>0$, there is a neighborhood of $c$ such that $f>0$ in that neighborhood. If $c\in(a,b)$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $f>0$ in $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$. If you cant take a open interval like that, so $c$ is on the boundary of $[a,b]$, that is, $c=a$ and $c=b$. In the case $c=a$, for continuity of $f$, you exists a $\delta>0$ such that $f>0$ in $[a,a+\delta)$, and similar for $c=b.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** There’s no reason to believe that $f(x)>f(c)$ for any $x$.

However, by continuity, if $f(c)>0$, then there’s a $\delta$ such that

$$|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon =\tfrac12f(c)$$

That is, $-\tfrac12 f(c)<f(x) - f(c)< \tfrac12 f(c)$, so in particular $0<\tfrac12 f(c)<f(x)$. This means that
$$\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta}f(x)\; dx\geq 2\delta\cdot
     \tfrac12 f(c)>0$$

Now finish it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also show it without "epsilontic", if you are allowed to use the following facts:

- $(1)$: Since $f$ is continuous, we know $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on $[a,b]$
- $(2)$: $f(x) \geq 0$ on $[a,b] \Rightarrow F(x)$ is increasing. Especially $F(a) \leq F(x) \leq F(b)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

Now, assume $\int_a^bf(t)dt = 0$. From $(2)$ follows $0 =F(a) \leq F(x) \leq F(b) =0 \Rightarrow F(x) = 0$ on $[a,b]$.

Hence, from $(1)$ we conclude $f(x) = F'(x) =0$. This is a **contradiction** to $f(c) > 0$ for some $c \in (a,b)$.